# How can I get center-line of a complex shaped polygon

Tags: python, geometry

Given coordinates of a polygon and I want to write a function that returns me a centerline coordinates of that polygon.
Centerline is actually a polyline.

[image: This image explains my question more clearly]

Comment: A starting point could be to iterate around your polygon and classify each wall as "end-walls"  or not - i.e. walls that should have a red dot on the line or not. You could base this classification on if the points after are both on the same side of the "end-wall" youre testing

Comment: You want to obtain it mathematically or from an image? Because from in image with medial-axis function from the scikit-image module it is pretty straight forward

Comment: just need python function which takes coordinate (extracted from Autocad file using python ezdxf library) values of a polygon which returns center polyline.

Comment: I had a similar requirement to this, in my case I had rectangles that I had to connect with a medial axis. I used a collision detection algorithm to determine if the rectangles were touching so I could extend/collapse the center lines. You can look at my algorithm here: https://jsfiddle.net/raulbojalil/jwy674on/116/

Answer (score 8):

You could try uisng the [centerline](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline) library. It supports [multipolygons](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline/blob/0.6.3/tests/conftest.py#L41) and [complex polygons](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline/blob/0.6.3/tests/conftest.py#L65) as input (basically any input that [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#geometric-objects) supports), and outputs `Centerline` objects which are [`MultiLineString`s](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#MultiLineString).

From what you've described, you should create a `Polygon` or a `MultiPolygon` object with `shapely` using the given points as input, and pass the (multi)polygon object as input to the `Centerline` class. Once you have the `Centerline` objects, you can perform any operations you would perform on a `MultiLineString` object. An example is available in the [README.md](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline#features) file:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Polygon
>>> from centerline.geometry import Centerline

>>> polygon = Polygon([[0, 0], [0, 4], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
>>> attributes = {"id": 1, "name": "polygon", "valid": True}

>>> centerline = Centerline(polygon, **attributes)
>>> centerline.id == 1
True
>>> centerline.name
'polygon'
>>> centerline.geoms
<shapely.geometry.base.GeometrySequence object at 0x7f7d24116210>
```

There is also a command line script for converting files. If the file is supported by [GDAL/OGR](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-list-of-ogr-drivers-alphabetically-a-z), the script should be able to convert it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18jGWtT7GqOPn_Qw8N8yekLN2-llLS1lz/view?usp=sharing  This link is the output of the T-shaped polygon using Centerline library but what I really wanted is clearly mentioned in the image mentioned in the question especially for T-shape.     Could you explain your logic of the centerline library so I can implement it on my problem?

Comment: The `centerline` library uses a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) to construct the centerline. The boundary of the polygon is densified, and the points are used as a baseline for the diagram. All diagram vertices that are located completely within the polygon are added to the centerline. 

However, if you want to achieve the exact result as show in the first question' image, i.e. a centerline with half as many points as there are in the polygon, the `centerline` library is not a good fit. In that case, you'll need a different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear to me how your task is precisely stated, i.e., given an arbitrary simple polygon, how is your function resp. its result really defined?

Given that your red lines are made of straight lines, a solution based on Voronoi diagrams (or its truncated version, the medial axis) is maybe not what you want, as it contains parabolic arcs as well (unless the polygon is convex)?

However, there is also the [straight skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton), which I mentioned in a [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77681599/8756717). It consists of straight-line segments only. Both skeleton structures have the property to be homotopy-equivalent to the original shape, see [this paper](https://conference.imp.fu-berlin.de/eurocg18/download/paper_17.pdf).

[image]