# Given a complex polygon, how can you either get a set of rectangles or center-line in Python?

Tags: python, geometry

Say that we have the following polygon:

[image: Polygon]

Now I'm looking for one of two results, where either problem will help me continue my current tasks. So I would just need one of the following two problems to be solved:

1. Calculate the center line of the polygon:

[image: center line]

Now I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645727/how-can-i-get-center-line-of-a-complex-shaped-polygon) post already, however the library used is outdated and I haven't managed to make it work properly.

2. Split the polygon into separate rectangles that fill up the entire polygon, non-overlapping.

[image: polygon split to rectangles]

Note that this is a very simple example of the kind of polygon whose solution I would need. I would need the exact same for a much more complex polygon, say the following:

[image: complex polygon]

So as I said, I need one of these 2 problems solved. Problem 1 is just a way to generate a solution for problem 2. Having the polygon split into distinct rectangles is the final goal.

Are there any resources that could help with this?

(Also pardon my paint-skills)

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific about what you want and the conditions under which you're working. There's no common definition for a "center line" of an arbitrary polygon and *rectangulation* of an arbitrary polygon isn't always possible.

Comment: In what format do you get this polygon?  What guarantees do you have about it?

Comment: For problem (1), consider using the [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). For problem (2), you didn't introduce a cost function, so very simple algorithms should be suitable. First, color with [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). Then, you could greedily scan across rasters, whittling the shape down so it's smaller and smaller. Or the simplest approach is to discretize to integer lattice points and declare that each colored unit square is an output rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for all feedback! Apologies for not introducing all details.

Context: the above figures represent wall-segments in a building. I have a way of detecting the bounding-boxes for the walls, however I have to turn the boxes into actual wall (line) objects rather than polygons. Thus the need for the rectangles.

@Samwise the input is just a list of (x,y) points. Every angle is 90 degrees, or pi/2 rads. Points are sorted s.t. iterating through all points creates a closed polygon without overlapping/crossing lines

Comment: @J_H thank you, this is very helpful! I will try looking into it :)