# Getting center line of a complex shape

Tags: c#, geometry

First of all sorry for the bad title, but i found it difficult to summarize the topic in a single phrase.

Second things second: the question.

I have a list of points that define a complex shape by its contour, with its thickness and all.
I need to "shrink" the shape until i get a single line with no thickness, but that maintains the semblance of the original shape.

[Simplified image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zURiC.jpg)

In the image, in black what i have, and in red what i want to obtain.

My question is similar to this one:
[How can I get center-line of a complex shaped polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645727/how-can-i-get-center-line-of-a-complex-shaped-polygon)

but it doesn't really solve my issue.

Any suggestions?
I'm using C#, if it's a needed info.

I don't really know where to start with this

Comment: a thought how I'd approach this: apply a delauney triangulation to the points, compute the circumcenter for each triangle and connect these for neighboring triangles. You'll probably have to clean the line up and remove squiggles. If you have only the edge points, I'd add/interpolate points until they are not much more than the thickness of that figure apart.

Answer (score 0):

This seem fairly similar to "[Skeletonization](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm)", or "[thinning](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm)".

These are so called morphology operations that are performed on binary image data. So if you have any other kind of shape you could convert it to a raster image first.

Note that I'm using "white" = 1, and "black" = 0. A basic algorithm might look something like:

For all pixels:

1. Ignore it if it is black
2. If all neighbors are white, keep it white
3. If some neighbors are white and some are black

   1. Keep white if there are black, non-connected neighbors. I.e. neighbor pixels that only connected to each other thru the pixel we are examining.
   2. Keep it if there is a single white neighbor
   3. Otherwise, set it to black
4. Repeat from start until no further change is done

Example regarding point 3

```
//Keep white examples
0 1 1    0 0 1     1 0 1    0 0 1 
0 1 0    0 1 0     0 1 1    1 1 1 
0 1 0    0 0 0     0 1 0    0 0 1 

//Set black examples
0 0 1    0 0 1     1 0 1    1 1 1 
0 1 1    0 1 1     1 1 1    1 1 1 
0 1 1    0 0 0     1 1 1    0 0 0
```

The point here is to keep pixels that are part of a single 1 pixel wide line, or an endpoint to the line, and remove pixels that are part of the border.

OpenCV or the .Net wrapper emguCV have a [method for thinning](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.1/document/html/c161ec98-b276-1bac-496a-463a38f93211.htm). But I have not used it, so cannot comment on its usage.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the Voronoi diagram or [straight skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) of polygonal shapes. Below you see the straight skeleton of your A-shape, with those edges touching the shape drawn thinner. They have a ton of applications. In particular, they have been used to compute center lines of road networks, which sounds like a similar problem to yours.

[image]

The picture looks similar for Voronoi diagrams (or a truncated version called medial axis). There is actually a related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62651638/8756717) using the `centerline` library, which uses Voronoi diagrams. (However, Voronoi diagram of a polygon is made of straight-line segments and parabolic arcs; it is not entirely straight.)

One can prove that the skeletons encode the "shape" in the sense that they are homotopy-equivalent to the shape. For further information I refer to [this paper](https://conference.imp.fu-berlin.de/eurocg18/download/paper_17.pdf).

If you want to learn more about straight skeletons and its applications, I refer to this [PhD thesis](https://www.sthu.org/research/publications/files/phdthesis.pdf) and there is also a book published at Shaker. The above picture, by the way, was computed by [Stalgo](https://www.sthu.org/code/stalgo/) with the input drawn in [Ipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipe_(software)), but there are also other implementations.